# How to keep the field in Antd by default without adding it?

Tags: reactjs, antd

In a React project, using Antd as design framework, a Form component has feature where on click of a button adds the new field, but, based on requirement some changes are to be done like, a field should be already available instead of adding new one. Head on to the code below for reference.

1. Form component

```
<Form
      name="dynamic_form_item"
      {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
<Form.List name="names">
{(fields, { add, remove }, { errors }) => (
<Form.Item>
             {/* This field should be already available instead of clicking 'Add Field' button */}
             <Form.Item
                  {...field}
                  validateTrigger={["onChange", "onBlur"]}
                  noStyle
                >
                  <Input
                    placeholder="passenger name"
                    style={{ width: "60%" }}
                  />
                </Form.Item>

              <Button
                type="dashed"
                onClick={() => add()}
                style={{ width: "60%" }}
                icon={<PlusOutlined />}
              >
                Add field
              </Button>
              <Form.ErrorList errors={errors} />
            </Form.Item>

)}
</Form.List>
</Form>
```

What could be appropriate solution?
Please refer codesandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-form-item-antd4169-forked-dl8od

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Add` function support config initial value.

Just add `initialValues` attribute to Form tag.

[Updated code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dynamic-form-item-antd4169-forked-unnuh)

```
    <Form
      name="dynamic_form_item"
      {...formItemLayoutWithOutLabel}
      initialValues={{ names: [""] }}
      onFinish={onFinish}
    >
```

Answer (score 0):

If your requirement is simply to add two fields at once, this could be done by modifying the onClick function of the plus button:

```
<Button
  type="dashed"
  onClick={() => {
    add();
    add();
  }}
  style={{ width: "60%" }}
  icon={<PlusOutlined />}
>
  Add field
</Button>;
```